How to obtain the device token to be able to make push notifications
could someone help me obtain the device token to be able to make personalized push notifications, specifically I want to make a chat and get a notification every time I send a message.
Try the external object ClientInformation.id as a token, but it is just a unique identifier of the device. Also check the RemoteNotifications external object but it is discontinued apparently there is a new way to send notifications but it still requires the device token. I already made the configurations in Google cloud messaging (FCM) and One Signal, I only need to obtain the token.

You have to use DeviceToken with the RegistrationService as shown here: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?18149,HowTo%3A%20Use%20a%20Device%27s%20Registration%20Service%20for%20Push%20Notifications
